# Dataloader converts text field with value of 0001 to 1 with Update operation

Tags: apex, data-loader, data

I have a requirement where I need to provide a company no. to all accounts i.e. unique. Currently I have 50 accounts and they don't have company no. and the format of the company no. be same as auto number type example "0001". I tried every possible way but salesforce convert "0001" to "1" by default though Company no. is text field.
Any help will be appreciated. Data was updated using data loader using a csv and inn CSV company no. column is text type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you saying the company number should be unique but "1" should be equal to "01" which should be equal to "001", etc?

Comment: This sounds like your CSV does not contain the data which you believe it does. If the field in Salesforce is defined as Text - the leading zeroes will not be stripped. If you used a tool like Excel to save your data in CSV format, the leading zeroes were likely stripped during this step. Double check using a text editor that your CSV field values contain the correct values with leading zeroes intact.

Comment: If you open the .csv file with notepad, zeroes will be there. If you dont want to delete the leading zeroes by excel, then you have to give the custom format of the field. Click the drop arrow under Number format category, select custom and define the format with 0. If I want to display 0123, then i will give number format as 0000.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure on what you're asking, but it sounds like you are using Excel to massage your data prior to loading it, which automatically strips off leading zeroes when you double-click on a CSV file to open it in Excel.

What you'll need to do is:

1. Rename the file to have an extension .txt
2. Open Excel first
3. Go to File > Open and open the *.txt file from #1
4. Follow the wizard to open your file, specifying delimiters and setting the column with the leading zeroes as Text
5. Massage your data
6. Save your file in csv format - it will still have a .txt extension
7. Rename the file to have a .csv extension
8. Run your data load

Alternately, it may be that your ID field is a number field, in which case Salesforce will automatically strip off all zeroes regardless of what you do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, your help is really appreciated and I have learned some new concepts to handle data in CSV, but for this problem I have figured it out in some other way. You can created another field of type Autonumber and enable the check box "Generate auto number for existing records", there is no use of data loader.